# How to not render an attachment

Tags: reactjs, botframework, web-chat

I am using botframework-webchat in a react app which is connected to a skillbot from which I send custom card attachments and render custom components.

I want to build a component that executes some code but does not render any visual box on screen.

```
const attachmentMiddleware = (properties) => () => next => card => {
  return (
          switch(card.attachment.contentType) {
              case 'application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive.addUserDetails':  
                return false;
              case 'application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive.locationpicker':  
                return  <LocationPicker/> 
  default: return next(card);
}
  )
}
```

My expectation is that when I `return false` the component will not render. Well the component does not render but the out speech box does render an empty box.
[Bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSE3W.png)

How can I implement this so that the outer speech box does not render at all as in the picture below when I return false from the attachmentMiddleware?
[Good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWKtF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better place to do this is just thru Web Chat's `store`.

This is because the `store` receives the activities first and then any middleware acts second. So, because the activity has the attachment, the `attachmentMiddleware` will necessarily render *something* even if you pass in `false` or `null`.

Therefore, if you want to not render anything at all for an adaptive card, you should filter for it in the `store` returning `false` or `null` at that point. Then, the middleware won't even register its presense and nothing will be rendered.

```js
const store = window.WebChat.createStore( {}, ( { dispatch } ) => next => async action => {
  if ( action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY' ) {
    const { activity } = action.payload;
    console.log('INCOMING ACTIVITY ', activity);
    if (activity.attachments && activity.attachments[0].contentType === 'application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive') {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return next(action);
} );

[ ... ]

window.WebChat.renderWebChat( {
  directLine: directLine,
  store: store
}, document.getElementById('webchat') );
```